# Spring JdbcTemplate Prepared Statements with SQL Server 2012

Tags: java, sql, sql-server, spring, jdbctemplate

I'm trying to use prepared statements with JDBC Template and SQL Server 2012. I used this to execute the statement:

```
jdbcTemplate.query(PreparedStatementCreator psc, PreparedStatementSetter pss, ResultSetExtractor rse);
```

From the JAVA part, everything is OK. Query is executed, and I get what I need, but the issue is database performance. When I fire up tracing, I can see that statement is being prepared, than executed, but than UNPREPARED! I'm not sure why. Than, the whole point of prepared statements is lost, since the query execution plan is being erased from the cache, and it has to be prepared again for the next usage.

Please, does anybody have an idea why SQL Server is unprepareing  the statements, and how to prevent it from happening?

Thanks in advance!